# Draw two boxes on a slanted plane in a mechanical illustration

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider:

[image]

I need help drawing the two boxes on an inclination.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (2,3) coordinate (A) - - (8,0) coordinate (B)
- - (2,0) coordinate (C) pic [draw,->] {angle};
\fill[pattern=north west lines](2,-1) rectangle(9,0);
    \draw(7,.2 5) node[left] {$\theta$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is an *"inlination"*? Do you mean an *"[inclination](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inclination#Noun)"*?

Comment: yes I mean inclination.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to draw the two inclined boxes is to use a `scope` with a `rotate` applied:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (2,3) coordinate (A) 
    -- (8,0) coordinate (B)
    -- (2,0) coordinate (C) 
    -- cycle;
\fill[pattern=north west lines]
    (2,-1) rectangle(8,0);
    \draw(7,.2 5) node[left] {$\theta$};
    
\begin{scope}[rotate=atan((3-0)/(2-8))]
    \draw  [fill=cyan!40, densely dashed] ([shift={(-0.5,0)}]A) rectangle ++(1,0.5);
    \draw  [fill=red!20]                  ([shift={(-0.5,0)}]B) rectangle ++(1,0.5);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, calc, quotes, angles}

\def\inc{25}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  % incline
  \draw (0,0) coordinate(O) -- (180-\inc : 7) coordinate(A) |- coordinate (D) ($(O)+(0,-1)$) -- cycle;
  \draw[dashed] (O) -| coordinate (C) (A);
  \fill[pattern = north west lines] (D) rectangle (O);

  % measures
  \draw[|<->|] ($(A)+(-0.5, 0)$) -- ($(C)+(-0.5, 0)$) node[midway, left]{$h$};
  \pic["$\theta$", <->, draw, angle eccentricity = 1.2, angle radius = 1cm] {angle = A--O--C};


  % block
  \begin{scope}[rotate=180-\inc]
    \draw[shift={(A)}, dashed] ($(A)+(-0.4,0)$) rectangle ++ (0.8,-0.6);
    \draw (-0.4, 0) rectangle ++ (0.8,-0.6);
    \draw[-latex] (0.4, -1) -- (-0.4, -1) node[above, midway]{${\bf v}$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Plus a little animation

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt, tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, calc, quotes, angles}

\begin{document}

\foreach \inc in {60,58,...,20,22,24,...,60}
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (-8, -1.5) rectangle (1, 6);

    % incline
    \draw (0,0) coordinate(O) -- (180-\inc : 7) coordinate(A) |- coordinate (D) ($(O)+(0,-1)$) -- cycle;
    \draw[dashed] (O) -| coordinate (C) (A);
    \fill[pattern = north west lines] (D) rectangle (O);

    % measures
    \draw[|<->|] ($(A)+(-0.5, 0)$) -- ($(C)+(-0.5, 0)$) node[midway, left]{$h$};
    \pic["$\theta$", <->, draw, angle eccentricity = 1.2, angle radius = 1cm] {angle = A--O--C};


    % block
    \begin{scope}[rotate=180-\inc]
      \draw[shift={(A)}, dashed] ($(A)+(-0.4,0)$) rectangle ++ (0.8,-0.6);
      \draw (-0.4, 0) rectangle ++ (0.8,-0.6);
      \draw[-latex] (0.4, -1) -- (-0.4, -1) node[above, midway]{${\bf v}$};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution only for fun purposes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\pspicture(-1,-1)(8,5)
    \psframe[fillstyle=vlines,hatchsep=1pt,linestyle=none](0,-.5)(7,0)
    \pstTriangle[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none](0,0){A}(7,0){B}(0,4){C}
    \pstMarkAngle{C}{B}{A}{$\theta$}
    \pcline(C)(B)\naput[npos=-.05,labelsep=-\pslinewidth,nrot=:U]{\psframe(1,.5)\psframe(8,0)(9,.5)\pcline{->}(8.25,.75)(8.75,.75)\naput[labelsep=12pt]{\rput{*0}{$\vec{v}$}}}
    \pcline[offset=10pt]{|*-|*}(A)(C)\naput{$h$}
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A dot at the left corner was not intentionally made. It appears as a real bug.

Answer (score 3):

A [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) alternative, purely for comparison.  Compile this one with `lualatex` (or work out how to adapt it for plain MP).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    numeric theta; theta = 19;

    path box;
    box = unitsquare shifted 1/2 left 
          xscaled 34 yscaled 21 shifted 1/2 up
          rotated -theta;

    z0 = origin;
    z3 = 288 left;
    x4 = x3 = x2; x1 = x0;
    y1 = y2 = -34;
    z4 = whatever * (z3 rotated -theta);

    draw z0--z3 dashed evenly scaled 1/2;
    draw z0--z1--z2--z4--cycle;

    draw box withcolor 2/3 red;
    draw box shifted z4 dashed withdots scaled 1/4 withcolor 2/3 red;

    path a, h, v;  
    a = fullcircle scaled 112 cutbefore (z0--z4) cutafter (z0--z3);
    h = (z3--z4) shifted 10 left;
    v = subpath (3,2) of box shifted (10 up rotated -theta);

    draw a; label.lft("$\theta$", point 1/2 of a);
    drawarrow v; label.top("$v$", point 1/2 of v);
    drawdblarrow h; label.lft("$h$", point 1/2 of h);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If one is using Metafun, then instead of `unitsquare shifted 1/2 left shifted 1/2 up` one can use `fullcircle` which is defined as `unitsquare shifted - center unitsquare`

Comment: @Aditya did you mean `fullsquare` ?  but even if you did, then we only want to shift the box left, not center it...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant full square. I see now that I misread your code.

Answer (score 2):

Without calculating any rotation, you can use `decorations.markings` with `transform shape`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,   angles, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta, positioning} 
\tikzset{mynode/.style={
    inner sep=0pt,
    text width=1cm,
    minimum height=.5cm,
    transform shape, draw, anchor=south}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
\draw (2,3) coordinate (A) -- (8,0) coordinate (B) 
    -- (2,0) coordinate (C) pic ["$\theta$"'above left=-4pt and 12pt, draw, ->, angle radius=28pt] {angle}  -- cycle;

\path [decorate,
    decoration={
    markings,% switch on markings
    mark=at position 0 with {\node[mynode, dashed]{};},
    mark=at position 1 with {\node[mynode](V){};
    \draw[->] ([yshift=4pt]V.north west) node[above=20pt,transform shape, midway] {$v$} -- ([yshift=4pt]V.north east);}}
    ]
    (A) -- (B);

\fill[pattern=north west lines](C) rectangle ++(6,-1);

\draw[<->] ([xshift=-4pt]A) -- node[left] {$h$} ([xshift=-4pt]C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]